# Enable listing files over SSH in Monterey

Tags: ssh, sharing

I want to be able to `ls` files under `/Users/<username>/Downloads`. I am getting `Operation not permitted`. I am able to list them locally when in iTerm2 but not over SSH.

Comment: In System Preferences->Sharing->Remote Login, is the box that says, "Allow full disk access for remote users" checked?

Comment: Does iTerm have Full Disk Access in System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Full Disk Access?

Comment: @dronenb that was the issue - many thanks!